# View logs of electron-builder packaged AppX package

Tags: node.js, logging, electron, electron-builder, appx

I've created an Electron app and I'm packaging it using Electron Builder. I'm using the AppX (Windows Store) format for Windows.

- How can I view the app's logs i.e. console.logs from main node process?

I need to be able to view logs for the packaged version of the app as the app launches fine without AppX packaging, but fails with it.

- On macOS, Linux and 'Windows with NSIS' instead of AppX, launching the app via the command line is sufficient to view logs

I've already tried launching AppX packages from the command line:

The only way to launch Windows Store apps from the command line is to follow these steps:
From [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_store/starting-windows-10-store-app-from-the-command/836354c5-b5af-4d6c-b414-80e40ed14675)

> 1. Run `explorer.exe shell:AppsFolder` in **cmd**
> 2. Find the app, and create it's shortcut on the desktop
> 3. Open the shortcut's properties and copy the "Target" field
> 4. Run `get-appxpackage > list.txt` in **PowerShell**
> 5. Open the file (located in `%USERPROFILE%`)
> 6. Find and make a note of the *PackageFamilyName* and InstallLocation corresponding to the Target name copied earlier
> 7. Open the file AppxManifest.xml present in the InstallLocation
> 8. Search for "Executable=" in the file, make a note of the value of "*Application Id*" above the line containing "Executable=".
> 9. Run the command `explorer.exe shell:appsFolder\<PackageFamilyName>!<Application Id>`, substituting `<PackageFamilyName>` for the Package Family name noted earlier and `<Application Id>` for the Application Id noted earlier to run your app.

This works but doesn't actually connect node's stdout to the terminal

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you can see the log but the part where you launch the app from the command line seems like overcomplicated.

Here is a thread on how to launch an app from an appx/msix from the command line properly:

- [How to properly set AppExecutionAlias so the program could be launched from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55426605/how-to-properly-set-appexecutionalias-so-the-program-could-be-launched-from-comm)